# Figuring out which function to call for a plugin

Tags: plugin, magento2.4

I'm trying to create a plugin where if the final price is 0, instead of showing a price is should say "please call for pricing".

I created a plugin like this,  But I don't see any change.

```
<?php

namespace <Vendor>\<name>\Plugins;

class Product
{
    public function aftergetCatalogPrice(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product, $finalPrice)
    {
        $price = $product->getData('price');
        if ($price === 0) {
            $finalPrice = "Please call for pricing";
        } else {
            return $finalPrice;
        }
        return $finalPrice;
    }
}
```

I have a plugin that does call for pricing, but I don't see anything that could be overriding the price.

How can I figure out where the price is being set so I can override it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Vender\Module\etc\frontend\di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox" type="Vender\Modele\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox" />
</config>
```

> Vender\Module\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Pricing\Render;


use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Pricing\Renderer\SalableResolverInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\MinimalPriceCalculatorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\Price\PriceInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\RendererPool;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\SaleableInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;

class FinalPriceBox extends \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox
{
    protected $registry;


    public function __construct(Context $context, SaleableInterface $saleableItem, PriceInterface $price, RendererPool $rendererPool, array $data = [], SalableResolverInterface $salableResolver = null, MinimalPriceCalculatorInterface $minimalPriceCalculator = null,\Magento\Framework\Registry $registry)
    {
        $this->registry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context, $saleableItem, $price, $rendererPool, $data, $salableResolver, $minimalPriceCalculator);
    }

    protected function wrapResult($html)
    {
        $current_product = $this->registry->registry('current_product');

        if($current_product)
        {
            $price = $current_product->getData('price');
            if($price === 0){
                $result = 'Please call for pricing';
            }else{
                $result = parent::wrapResult($html);
            }
        }else{
            $result = parent::wrapResult($html);
        }

        return $result;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you. Why take the preference approach instead of the plugin approach? Isn't the plugin approach the recommended way for overriding a public method?